# Run a defined number of files using JAVA

Tags: java, java-8

I have a directory that contains 100 folder.
I want to choose randomly 10 files from that directory and do a treatment.

```
static File repertoire = new File("path");
    static File[] files = repertoire.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+ file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\scriptSh.sh");}
        }
    }
}
```

I want my code to be runned on only 10 files under my directory not on all of them.
Any help please.

Comment: your Q is confusing. So you want to pick random 10 files from any of those 100 folders that you have within the main dir?

Comment: `List<File> files = Arrays.stream(repertoire.listFiles())
                          .filter(file->file.isDirectory())
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(files);
files.stream()
          .limit(10)
          .forEach(file -> Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "
                  +file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\scriptSh.sh"));`

Comment: The placement of `static` in your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static File repertoire = new File("path");
static File[] files = repertoire.listFiles();
List<File> directories = new ArrayList<>();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        directories.add(file);
     }
}

Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
   File file randomElement = directories.get(rand.nextInt(directories.size()));
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start "+ file.getAbsolutePath()+"\\scriptSh.sh");
}
```

Comment: if multiple instance use the same instance of random, it has performance issue. so instead of you can use `ThreadLocalRandom` which creates a random instance per thread.

Comment: exactly, I don't want to run the same scrip multiple times. Each script should be runed once.

Comment: it worked but I removed each time the runned script from the list to run each time a different script.